# issue with %s with sqlalchemy core and sqlite

Tags: python

When I try to use the %s syntax with sqlalchemy and sqlite I get an error. The same syntax with postgresql works fine:

```
import sqlalchemy
e = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:////tmp/x.db?timeout=120000')
e.execute('select * from people where name = %s;', 'joe').fetchall()
```

I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1396, in _cursor_execute
    context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 301, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1790, in execute
    return connection.execute(statement, *multiparams, **params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1191, in execute
    params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1287, in _execute_text
    return self.__execute_context(context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1302, in __execute_context
    context.parameters[0], context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1403, in _cursor_execute
    context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1360, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    from e
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) near "%": syntax error 'select * from people where name = %s;' ('joe',)
>>>
```

Again, the exact same thing with postgres returns a list or rows.
Is this a bug?
Or is it expected?

Answer (score 3):

There is a small problem with string formatting in `'select * from people where name = %s;', 'joe'`

`%s` is used for string formatting, `%s` is expecting a % `some sort Data to be replaced` after the string

you should remove the `,` from `%s;', 'joe'` and add a `%`to get

```
In [10]: 'select * from people where name = %s;' %'joe'
Out[10]: 'select * from people where name = joe;'
```

Comment: yes, without that, string substitution isn't happening in python.

Comment: No it does not work. I'm not trying to use python substitution but sqlalchemy syntax. It works fine with postgresql, but not with sqlite.

Comment: @user1014841: for sqlalchemy, you need to escape `%` signs as `%%`

Answer (score 1):

I got around it by using the question mark syntax:

```
e.execute('select * from people where name = ?;', 'joe').fetchall()
```

This works with both sqlite <s>and postgres</s>.

From [the chapter about sqlalchemy in the Pylon's book](http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/introducing-the-model-and-sqlalchemy.html):

> Different databases use different markers (known as param styles) to label where the variables you pass to execute() should be inserted. The example above used SQLite which uses ? as the param style but if you tried to use MySQL or PostgreSQL you would need to use %s as the param style instead. The SQL would then look like this

The right answer is to user sqlalchemy "text" (see my other answer).

Comment: isn't this the same as your original post? did you mean ('select * from people where name = ?;' , 'joe') maybe?

Comment: You are right, I copied and pasted from my original post without fixing it. I have edited it now.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is given by [van](https://stackoverflow.com/users/99594/van) in his answer to [another of my posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717713/sqlachemy-weird-behaviour-with-s-on-a-select). The solution is to use [sqlalchemy "text"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#using-text). This works with both SQLite and postgreSQL (and I assume other servers as well), so you can write once and use it against different DB Servers (as long as you keep your sql generic of course).