# sqlachemy weird behaviour with %s on a select

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

e is my engine, i can do regular select, insert etc... with it, but when I want to do a "select or ignore" type questy, I get a weird behaviour:

```
e.execute('insert into users (username) select %s where not exists (select 1 from users where username = %s);', 'toto', 'toto')
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1416, in _cursor_executemany
    context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 298, in do_executemany
    cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
  File "/projects/bin/packages/pg8000/dbapi.py", line 243, in _fn
    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/projects/bin/packages/pg8000/dbapi.py", line 370, in executemany
    self._execute(operation, parameters)
  File "/projects/bin/packages/pg8000/dbapi.py", line 319, in _execute
    self.cursor.execute(new_query, *new_args)
  File "/projects/bin/packages/pg8000/interface.py", line 301, in execute
    self._stmt.execute(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/projects/bin/packages/pg8000/interface.py", line 136, in execute
    self._row_desc, cmd = self.c.bind(self._portal_name, self._statement_name, args, self._parse_row_desc, kwargs.get("stream"))
  File "/projects/bin/packages/pg8000/protocol.py", line 933, in _fn
    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/projects/bin/packages/pg8000/protocol.py", line 1116, in bind 
    return reader.handle_messages()
  File "/projects/bin/packages/pg8000/protocol.py", line 901, in handle_messages 
    retval = handler(msg, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/projects/bin/packages/pg8000/protocol.py", line 1155, in _bind_nodata
    reader.handle_messages()
  File "/projects/bin/packages/pg8000/protocol.py", line 906, in handle_messages 
    raise exc
pg8000.errors.ProgrammingError: (b'ERROR', b'23505', b'duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_pkey"')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1790, in execute
    return connection.execute(statement, *multiparams, **params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1191, in execute
    params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1287, in _execute_text
    return self.__execute_context(context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1297, in __execute_context
    context.parameters, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1423, in _cursor_executemany
    context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1360, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    from e
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) (b'ERROR', b'23505', b'duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_pkey"') 'insert into users (username) select %s where not exists (select 1 from users where username = %s);' [('x', 'o', 'x', 'o'), ('x', 'o', 'x', 'o')]
```

That value (xoxo) is not in that table, I get the same thing even when re-create the table from scratch.

Comment: I find it wierd that `xoxo` got translated into `('x', 'o', 'x', 'o'),`. Does your table have value `'x'`? If yes, this could be the reason for failure. Maybe you could try to issue `e.execute('insert into users (username) select %s where not exists (select 1 from users where username = %s);', ('toto',), ('toto',))` instead. However, ideally you should use [`sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) construct.

Answer (score 1):

can't reproduce with recent SQLA versions.  What SQLA version?  What pg8000 version?  See if you can upgrade your pg8000 to the latest, it's not really an active project. psycopg2 is much preferred for general use.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
e = create_engine("postgresql+pg8000://scott:tiger@localhost/test", echo=True)

c = e.connect()
t = c.begin()
c.execute("create table users (username varchar(50) primary key)")

for i in range(10):
    c.execute('insert into users (username) select %s where not exists '
        '(select 1 from users where username = %s);', 'toto', 'toto')

t.rollback()
```

output:

```
2012-12-07 09:48:15,381 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine select current_schema()
2012-12-07 09:48:15,382 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2012-12-07 09:48:15,387 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2012-12-07 09:48:15,387 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine create table users (username varchar(50) primary key)
2012-12-07 09:48:15,387 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2012-12-07 09:48:15,413 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine insert into users (username) select %s where not exists (select 1 from users where username = %s);
2012-12-07 09:48:15,413 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('toto', 'toto')
2012-12-07 09:48:15,422 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine insert into users (username) select %s where not exists (select 1 from users where username = %s);
2012-12-07 09:48:15,422 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('toto', 'toto')
2012-12-07 09:48:15,424 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine insert into users (username) select %s where not exists (select 1 from users where username = %s);
2012-12-07 09:48:15,424 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('toto', 'toto')
2012-12-07 09:48:15,426 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine insert into users (username) select %s where not exists (select 1 from users where username = %s);
2012-12-07 09:48:15,426 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('toto', 'toto')
2012-12-07 09:48:15,427 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine insert into users (username) select %s where not exists (select 1 from users where username = %s);
2012-12-07 09:48:15,427 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('toto', 'toto')
2012-12-07 09:48:15,428 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine insert into users (username) select %s where not exists (select 1 from users where username = %s);
2012-12-07 09:48:15,428 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('toto', 'toto')
2012-12-07 09:48:15,429 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine insert into users (username) select %s where not exists (select 1 from users where username = %s);
2012-12-07 09:48:15,429 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('toto', 'toto')
2012-12-07 09:48:15,431 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine insert into users (username) select %s where not exists (select 1 from users where username = %s);
2012-12-07 09:48:15,431 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('toto', 'toto')
2012-12-07 09:48:15,432 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine insert into users (username) select %s where not exists (select 1 from users where username = %s);
2012-12-07 09:48:15,432 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('toto', 'toto')
2012-12-07 09:48:15,433 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine insert into users (username) select %s where not exists (select 1 from users where username = %s);
2012-12-07 09:48:15,433 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('toto', 'toto')
2012-12-07 09:48:15,434 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK
```